# reportviewer 11 not working Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, report-viewer2010

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Reportviewer 11 and nothing shows up at the run time. I have checked the web.config file, Ref assemblies , IIS & setting (adding all the handlers and changing the app domain), added the assembly refrences on aspx page. But still nothing comes up. When check the view source it says 
Report Viewer Configuration Error 
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

which I have already done :(

It also gives me an error : Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.

Any Help appreciated . Thank you .

Here is the code:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</httpHandlers>


    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>


<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
  <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>

</handlers>
```

Here is code behind:
 var query = (from p in db.PurchaseOrders
                             where p.POID == yourValue
                             select new
                             {
                                 PurchaseOrderNumber = p.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                                ..........

```
                         });

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "App_Data/POReport.rdlc";
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource rdS = new ReportDataSource("PODataset", query.ToList());
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdS);
            ReportViewer1.DataBind();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Here is the aspx code

```
   <br />
```

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering ="false">
        <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="EDICheckerTest/App_Data/POReport.rdlc">

        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: You should post your code and relevant configuration sections. Also, do you have JavaScript enabled or disabled on your browser. Have you tried using other browsers? Why did you tag this as Visual Studio?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @msm8bball I have used linq query to fill the data and data is coming but even when I put a reportviewer control with a scriptmanager on page it gives me the same error. I thought they are not compatible or I am missing any update .. I know I sound silly .I am doing it for the last 2 days ...

Comment: As I said previously, you need to post your code and relevant configuration sections.

Comment: Please edit your question with all relevant information needed for someone to answer your question. You don't need to put the code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.  VS 2012 project with ms report.  Was working (using pdf and no viewer control) using version 10.  Switched to version 11 over error messages when i attempted to add a viewer control.  Now it doesn't render, I just get the following message.  However, the entry that is indicated in the message is already in web.config (pasted it under the entry that was already there and it matches char for char)

I did notice that even though both reportviewer.common and webforms are in my assembly cache, There is no reportviewer.common dll in my Visual Studio 11\reportviewer folder.

Report Viewer Configuration Error

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file